# Strike a paragraph of text

Tags: paragraphs, strikeout

I want to strike obliquely one or more paragraphs of text, to indicate cancellation, like in this picture:

[image]

I would need to strike also if the paragraph spans in two pages.

[image]

I tried the cancel package, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What would it look like if you were to strike a paragraph over a page boundary?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try tcolorbox. Be aware that even if looks like normal text, it is nevertheless a box and e.g. spacing before and after can differ a bit to normal spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,
 enhanced jigsaw,
 opacityback=0,
 sharp corners,
 parbox=false,
 boxrule=0mm,
 top=0mm,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,
 boxsep=0pt,
 frame hidden,
 parbox=false,
 before upper=\indent\strut,
 before=\par,after=\par,
 finish={\draw[thick,red] ([xshift=3cm]frame.north)--([xshift=-3cm]frame.south);}
]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]